# Determine if a string contains a substring

Tags: java, string

I wanna know how I can find if string A has string B in it without breaking apart the whole string; also finding how much times it repeats using loops. BTW, it doesn't have to be case-sensitive. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
    String st = abababajjjabababb;
    String aba = null;
    String st2 = aba;
    int i = 0;
    char ch = st.charAt(i);
    int j;
    for (j = 0;j < st2.length();j = j + 1){
        for (int k = 0; k < st.length(); k = k + 1){
            if(ch == st.charAt(j)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j == st2.length()) {

        }
    }
    System.out.println("the letters in s1 dont repeat in s2");

}
```

I know how to find if `st2` repeats in `st` but I don't know how to program it to tell me how many times it repeats.

Thanks! I got my answer and I'm done with this program, thanks to you all that gave suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking about Java or JavaScript? Looks like Java to me.

Comment: Are you interested in Java or Javascript? They're entirely different languages - it doesn't look like Javascript to me. And when you say "it doesn't have to be case sensitive" do you mean it must be case-insensitive?

Comment: You might be missing some quotes there.

Comment: If you really want to know how to implement it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: For a case-sensitive solution, use [String.indexOf(String, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-).

Answer (score 2):

*I know how to find if st2 repeats in st but I don't know how to program it to tell me how much times it repeats.*

You could remove all occurrences of the substring and then divide by the length of the substring to get the number of occurrences.

```
String st = "abababajjjabababb";
String st2 = "aba";

int intOccurrences = (st.length() - st.replace(st2, "").length()) / st2.length();
```

Haven't used Java in a bit so I'm a little rusty.

For your example, this would return:

```
(17 - 8) / 3
= 3 occurrences
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use count to count how many times it repeats. just declare count as a int. and have count ++ everytime it goes through the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) from Apache commons lang to count the number of matches of a substring in a string:

```
int numOccurrences = StringUtils.countMatches(st, st2);
```